# Google Mini won't start

Tags: google-search-appliance

Hopefully this is the best place to ask this...  We have a Google Mini that now gets stuck on the Enterprise Network service step and won't go past that.  Is there anything we can do?  We have probably been out of support for around 8 years, and everyone who set it up has left our organization.  I found this post about it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Search-Appliance-Help/91AhqGXc4HM, but the link at the end doesn't work anymore...  Hopefully someone has a solution to that problem, that doesn't involve buying a new Search Appliance...

Comment: Our DNS setup had changed since the last successful reboot.  It sounds like that is stored somewhere in a config file.  Right now we can't boot to fix the setting.  Does anyone know the location of that, so that we can mount the drive from another machine, change it, and the reinstall the drive in the mini?

Comment: Those settings looked ok, but I did see a Google IP address in the settings.  Would it be calling back to Google and trying to connect to a service that moved or doesn't exist anymore?  APC_MAP = {'ent1': '216.239.43.144-1'}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly edit the configuration of the Google Mini unless you can boot it up and get to the configuration services.  The hard drives are encrypted.

Since the Mini is a licensed piece of hardware and will have expired by now you won't be able to have Support log in to resolve the issue.

You should look at replacement technology at this point.

Comment: The drive isn't encrypted...  I just had to load it from a Linux OS.  Maybe they protected later models, but ours isn't.  We did look at their new appliances (through your company actually), but right now, that is was outside what we can spend, as a non-profit organization.  We will probably be able to get one next year or later, but we need to get ours going for at least the rest of this year.

Comment: Also, when we bought ours, it was a one time purchase, and you just paid for updates (if you wanted them).  It didn't stop functioning out of a license, as it sounds like the current appliances do today (which makes each search cost around $0.50-$1 with our current usage and the prices I got from one of your sales associates)..